# Как подключить внешнюю видеокарту к MacBook Pro 2019?

Tags: nvidia, видеокарта, macbook

Подскажите возможно ли подключить внешнюю видеокарту, в моем случае GTX 1070, подключить к моему MacBook Pro 2019 не для игр. НЕкоторые программы требует более мощное видеоядро. Расскажите как подключить, и возможно ли это сделать.

Comment: А через type c нельзя это все сделать?

Comment: Драйвер нужен, без драйвера ничего работать у вас не будет. А macOS не дружит с NVIDIA